# Receive data via AJAX with jQuery Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, flot

I have a problem with jQuery flot.

**PHP output (not JSON):**

```
[[1, 153], [2, 513], [3, 644]] ~~ [[1, 1553], [2, 1903], [3, 2680]]
```

**jQuery call:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'xxx.php',
    success: function (data) {
        var dataArray = data.split('~~'),
        dataArray1 = dataArray[0],
        dataArray2 = dataArray[1],
        plot = $.plot($('#xxx'), [{
            data: dataArray1,
            color: colours[0]
        },
        {
            data: dataArray2,
            color: colours[1],
            points: {
                show: true,
            }
        },
        ], {
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: .6,
                    align: 'center'
                }
            },
            grid: {
                show: true,
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                autoHighlight: true,
                borderWidth: true,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
            },
            xaxis: {
                show: false
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Taking the data in this way, I'm trying to use jQuery Flot but does not work...

Whereas, I can by separating data:

**First label:**

```
[[1, 153], [2, 513], [3, 644]]
```

**Second label:**

```
[[1, 1553], [2, 1903], [3, 2680]]
```

[image: jQuery Flot Problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have recieved a string that was not qualified as JSON data. Then you've splitted it on two strings, that are still not JSON. Then you trying to instantiate `plot` object with `data: your_string_value`. Here `plot` waiting of an object, not string.
Try to define `data` of your `plot` this way: `data:$.parseJSON( dataArray1 )`

Comment: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character` returned the error.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. My problem is the character of ('). Worked with ("). Again thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I'll share a Simple example jquery Flot with ajax for basic understanding purpose.

See this page and let change it into ajax : http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/making-first-jquery-flot-line-chart.html

First, you must successful showing the chart as described without ajax. Don't forget to put height and width in div tag if you don't include css file.:

```
<div id="flot-placeholder" style="width: 100%; height: 260px"></div>
```

If ok, then follow this step.

STEP 1 : Put the script inside a function:

```
<script> 
   function show_chart(data) {

    // this will be moved to php file
    //var data = [[1, 130], [2, 40], [3, 80], [4, 160], [5, 159], [6, 370], [7, 330], [8, 350], [9, 370], [10, 400], [11, 330], [12, 350]];

                var dataset = [{label: "line1",data: data}];

                var options = {
                    series: {
                        lines: { show: true },
                        points: {
                            radius: 3,
                            show: true
                        }
                    }
                };

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"), dataset, options);
                });
        }
</script>
```

STEP 2 : Create sample.php.

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
if($_POST) 
{
$id      = $_POST['id'];  

$arr = array();

$arr = [[1, 130], [2, 40], [3, 80], [4, 160], [5, 159], [6, 370], [7, 330], [8, 350], [9, 370], [10, 400], [11, 330], [12, 350]];   

echo json_encode($arr);

 }?>
```

Note : $arr that moved from the first script then become only a sample data. You should make a php class or function that fetch data from database and return as array format as shown in $arr.

STEP 3 : Create simple ajax to get the response and render the chart  :

```
       var id = 1;
       $.post('/..if any folder../sample.php', {
        id : id, 
        }, function(response){                  

        var data = JSON.parse(response);

        show_chart(data); // call function and render the chart in <div id="flot-placeholder"></div>

        });
```

Step Finish.

In some cases, we may need two or more data type. Then just add this to the code :

inside sample.php :

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();

$arr1 = [[1, 130], [2, 40], [3, 80], [4, 160], [5, 159], [6, 370], [7, 330], [8, 350], [9, 370], [10, 400], [11, 330], [12, 350]];  
$arr2 = [[1, 130], [2, 40], [3, 80], [4, 160], [5, 159], [6, 370], [7, 330], [8, 350], [9, 370], [10, 400], [11, 330], [12, 350]];  
// put more if rquired

echo json_encode($arr1,$arr2); // put more array if required
```

inside ajax :

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);

    var result1 = data[0]; // response data from $arr1
    var result2 = data[1]; // response data from $arr2
```

Sorry for long description. Hope it will help.

Just for fun :

Some people don't want to show 'sample.php' in the console log. For this purpose we can simply change 'sample' as a folder and create index.php inside it and in the ajax we just direct the url to the folder like this :

```
$.post('/..if any folder../sample/'), {  // this will open index.php
```